# Deal 5 cards to Player1 and 5 cards to Player2 from a deck of 52 cards

Tags: probability, combinatorics, card-games

What is the probability that :
**a)** Player1 has 2 aces
**b)** Player2 has 2 kings
**c)** Player1 has 2 aces **and** Player2 has 2 kings

For **a)** I did :
$$\frac{2! \cdot {{50}\choose{3,3}} }{ {52}\choose{5,5} }$$

But I think that's wrong.
And I know that the result of **a)** will equal **b)**.
And I have no clue for **c)**

Comment: Do you mean _exactly_ 2, or _at least_ 2?

Comment: Player 2 should receive five cards.  It looks like you dealt player 2 just three cards.  It would help if you explained your reasoning.

Comment: exactly 2 Arthur

Comment: N. F. Taussig : There is 2! ways to organize 2 cards (here 2 aces). The total possibilities of distributing 2 hands of 5 cards from a deck of 52 is (52 ; 5,5)
Now I have distributed my 2 aces to player1 to I have (50 ; 3,3) possibilities to deal my 50 cards left

Comment: @RomainB. so, why are you only dealing three cards to player 2?  Also, you don't want to deal any other aces to player 1.

Comment: Oh yes.. so that's (50 ; 3,5) ?

Comment: Not exactly, @RomainB.; you have to ensure that player 1 gets no aces. Why not $pick$ cards, instead of $distributing$ them?

Comment: I don't get it, I'm a bit lost in combinatorics

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's say we deal to Player 1 first. Out of the 4 aces in the deck he gets exactly 2. There are $\binom{4}{2}$ many ways to choose the aces. Out of the 48 non-ace cards he gets 3. There are $\binom{48}{3}$ ways to choose those. Out of the remaining 47 cards (2 aces and 45 non-aces) Player 2 gets 5 cards. Thus the probability that Player 1 gets exactly 2 aces is:
$$
\frac{\binom{4}{2}\binom{48}{3}\binom{47}{5}}{\binom{52}{5}\binom{47}{5}} = \frac{\binom{4}{2}\binom{48}{3}}{\binom{52}{5}}.
$$
Note that Player 2 doesn't really matter for this.
As you already said, b) is just the same. See if you can do c) now.

**Edit:** Answer to c):

There are $3$ cases: Player $1$ has no king, one king or two kings. Let $i \in \{0,1,2\}$ be the number of kings in Player $1$'s hand. There are $\binom{4}{2}$ many ways to choose the $2$ aces for Player $1$ and $\binom{4}{i}$ many ways to choose the $i$ kings that Player $1$ has, the remaining $3-i$ cards of Player $1$ come from the $44$ cards that are neither an ace nor a king. Then for Player $2$ there are $\binom{4-i}{2}$ ways to choose the kings and finally we need to choose the remaining $3$ cards from the cards that are not in Player $1$'s hand and not kings (There are $52-5-4+i = 43+i$ such cards). Hence the probability is 
$$
\frac{1}{\binom{52}{5}\binom{47}{5}}\sum_{i=0}^2\binom{4}{2}\binom{4}{i}\binom{44}{3-i}\binom{4-i}{2}\binom{43+i}{3}.
$$

Comment: c) is just a*b=a^2=b^2 then ?

Comment: Not quite. I made an edit explaining the answer.

Comment: So if the answer depends on i, it means that those 2 events (2 aces and 2 kings) ARE dependent ?

Comment: The answer does not depend on $i$. You can write it out as $\frac{\binom{4}{2}}{\binom{52}{5}\binom{47}{5}}\left(\binom{44}{3}\binom{4}{2}\binom{43}{3} + \binom{4}{1}\binom{44}{2}\binom{3}{2}\binom{44}{3} + \binom{4}{2}\binom{44}{1}\binom{2}{2}\binom{45}{3}\right)$.

Comment: So they are independant ?

Comment: The two events "Player 1 has exactly two aces." and "Player 2 has exactly 2 kings" are dependent, since if we know that Player 1 has exactly 2 aces that makes it less likely for him to have a king.